# Is the "User Accounts" icon listed in the Freedesktop Icon Naming Specification?

Tags: icons, application-development

In the System Settings, there's an entry at the bottom called "User Accounts", and it has this icon:

[image]

I've looked through the [Freedesktop Icon Naming Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html), but I can't seem to find anything that matches it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon is called `config-users` from what I can tell. At least I see this on my system in the icon list in Glade.